# override the play/pause button media player android

Tags: android

I have android app with gridView and media player when I press on item some video played from start time to end time that I specify as the pressed item, and the item on the view will be color, but if the user want to continue the video he can press the play button on the media player and its working great, so I need the override the play button to move the color over the next item, my code:

```
                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                final int position, long id) {
        String path = Uri.parse(
                                "android.resource://com.example/"
                                + R.raw.v00).toString();
                videoView.setVideoPath(path);
                final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(
                        LessonUnit.this);
                mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.requestFocus();
                final Runnable stopVideoTask = new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        videoView.pause();
                    }
                };

                    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        videoView.seekTo(videoTimes.get(position)[0]);
                        videoView.start();
                        mediaController.postDelayed(stopVideoTask, videoTimes.get(position)[1]-videoTimes.get(position)[0]);

                    }
                });
```

Any Help ??!!

Comment: Don't ovveride that, just add some code.

Comment: where and how can I know if the play button is pressed to add some code ??

Comment: It's right when you call videoView.start(); and videoView.pause();